# Change the value of a KeyCloak user attribute in java

Tags: attributes, keycloak

I want to use a user attribute as a flag during the Keycloak authentication flow. How can I change the value of a user attributes in java (not using the api)? How do I reference that attribvute in a template (ftl file)
Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: I found it, its UserModel.setSingleAttribute(String name, String value)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I reference that attribute in a template (ftl file)

I think accessing to user attrs should be disabled by default. 
**Solution**: Set user attribute as form attribute.
Code for Form:

```java
@Override
protected Response createLoginForm(LoginFormsProvider form) {
    form.setAttribute("customattr", user.getFirstAttribute("customattr"));
    return form.createForm("your-page.ftl");
}
```

And in ftl:

```html
<label>${customattr}</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add or update a single attribute to a Keycloak-User like this:

```java
    @Transactional
    public void setAttributeByAuthentication(String attributeName, String attributeValue, Authentication auth) {

        // Get realm.
        RealmResource realmResource = this.getRealmResource();

        // Get Keycloak user based on current authentication.
        UserResource userResource = realmResource.users().get(this.getAccessTokenByAuthentication(auth).getSubject());
        UserRepresentation user = userResource.toRepresentation();
        user.singleAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue);
        userResource.update(user);
    }
```